# How to calculate a rolling IRR in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, irr

I have dataframe with two columns: CFs and NAV,(cashflows and net asset valuation) now want to calculate the rolling IRR.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Example:
CFs  NAV
-100  100
1     101
2     103
3     106
2     108
110   0

[image]

Comment: Maybe if you update your post with the formula of IRR, it will be easy?

Comment: Does it make sense to calculate 'rolling IRR' and not just IRR?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, use `expanding` to apply `irr`:

```
Python env: pip install numpy-financial
Anaconda env: conda install -c conda-forge numpy-financial

import numpy_financial as npf

df['IRR'] = df['CFs'].expanding(1).agg(npf.irr)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   CFs   NAV       IRR
0 -100   100       NaN
1    1   101 -0.990000
2    2   103 -0.853490
3    3   106 -0.664270
4    2   108 -0.558468
5  110     0  0.034784
```